# How to request an address within a Django project

Tags: python, django

this is my view

```
def mydate(request):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('date'),"%Y-%m-%d")
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

and i want call this view in another method in the django project

how to deal with this problem ？

Comment: Can you give a bit more description around what you're trying to do? If you want to call the view as a function you can just call it like you would any other function.

Comment: I now have a well written HTTP interface address (view), this interface address is a pass-through, and then get back. I'm going to call this address to get the information directly.

Answer (score 1):

yup you can do it

like this

```
def other_view(request):
    item = mydate()
// now do what you need to do
```

Comment: Maybe my needs are not a common habit. so I found another way
`   def mydate(date):
    return HttpResponse(date)

  def myview(request):
    date =  datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('date'),"%Y-%m-%d")
    mydate(date)`